# How do I customize the Group in Django?

Tags: python, django

I write a Django project, and I use the default Groups and Permissions.

When I list or retrieve the Group, the data is bellow:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "group02",
    "permissions": [
        22,
        23,
        24
    ]
}
```

I can not see the `permissions` name and the `users` belong to the `Group` instance.

How can I optimize this to satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the result in dajngo shell, then you can try this: `User.objects.values('id','username','groups','groups__permissions')`
If you are using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) then, you can use [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) as below;

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group,Permission,User


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id','name','permissions')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'groups')
```

**expected output** :

```
[
    {
            "id": 49,
            "username": "jerinpetergeorge",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NewGroup",
                    "permissions": [
                        "activity | activity | Can change activity"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test",
                    "permissions": [
                        "activity | activity | Can add activity",
                        "activity | activity | Can change activity",
                        "activity | activity | Can delete activity"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

    {
        ...
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you mean I should create the new `GroupSerializer`? do not use the 
default? So, there will be more API?

Comment: I think django does not provide any *default serializer_class*  to serialize the *user* data